# Language translation file PHP- automatically

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter

How I can translate very much values automatically- to aother language

For example:

en.php

```
$lang['activities'] = 'Activities';
$lang['add_item'] = 'Add Item';
$lang['add_payment'] = 'Add Payment';
$lang['add_task'] = 'Add Task';
```

to

de.php

```
$lang['activities'] = 'New Translation';
$lang['add_item'] = 'New Translation';
$lang['add_payment'] = 'New Translation';
$lang['add_task'] = 'New Translation';
```

Thank you

Comment: please elaborate little bit...

Comment: Google Translate API, isn't something which you want to use for your all your translations.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this php tutorial to access Google Translate Api:
http://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/